# A question on Polygon triangulation

Tags: geometry, polygons, triangulation

The following is an extract from Dennis Zill's *A First Course in Complex Analysis with Applications*. The concern is in the highlighted sentence which is not even true for the Figure (7 sides, 5 triangles)

[image]

Comment: It's incorrect, but all that matters is that the polygon can be decomposed into a finite number of triangles.

Comment: In fact any simple polygon (meaning non-self-intersecting and without holes) can be triangulated without introducing new vertices, and there will always be $n-2$ triangles in this case — so the case in the figure always happens!

Comment: @Milten, but it contradicts with the highlighted statement.

Comment: @Eureka Yes, I think it’s a typo/oversight from the authors. They’re not technically wrong, since you can easily subdivide an $(n-2)$-triangulation to make an $n$-triangulation (just add a vertex inside one of the triangles and connect it to the three vertices). But it’s a bit of a weird statement to make, when the standard and well-known result is $n-2$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement **is** true. It does not say that **every** triangulation must have $n$ triangles. But it is true, though non-trivially, that every non-self-intersecting polygon with $n$ sides can be triangulated with $n$ triangles. Now it is a separate issue that the diagram shown is misleading and does not correspond to the true statement...